# python gnuplotpy with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, gnuplot

I've been trying to print following data with gnuplot.py:

```
data = [[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 15, 17, 45), 16.00], [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 16, 17, 45), 15.98], [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 17, 17, 45), 15.94]]
```

So I have started like this:

```
gp=Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
gp('set data style linespoints')
gp('set xdata time')
gp('set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"')
gp('set xrange ["2012-12-20":"2013-02-12"]')
gp.plot(data)
```

and I get following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Gnuplot/_Gnuplot.py", line 285, in plot
    self._add_to_queue(items)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Gnuplot/_Gnuplot.py", line 255, in _add_to_queue
    self.itemlist.append(PlotItems.Data(item))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Gnuplot/PlotItems.py", line 549, in Data
    data = utils.float_array(data[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Gnuplot/utils.py", line 33, in float_array
    return numpy.asarray(m, numpy.float32)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 230, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Then, I've tried to convert it to following list:

```
[['2013-01-15', 16.00], ['2013-01-16', 15.98], ['2013-01-17', 15.94]]
```

Same results.

Does anyone has a clue where is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9720624/748858) might be helpful to you ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem (I believe) is in this line inside of gnuplot-py which I pulled out of the traceback:

```
return numpy.asarray(m, numpy.float32)
```

What is happening is ultimately that gnuplot-py is trying to convert your date-time (or string) data into a `numpy.float32` object.  If you're willing to jump through some hoops though, we could probably make this work.

---

*Upon inspecting the source, this portion of the solution might not actually be necessary.*
The first thing you'll need to do is change that line inside `utils.py` to use `numpy.float64` instead of `numpy.float32` and then re-install `gnuplot-py`.  This is so that we can use the somewhat standard epoch notation.  (alternatively, you could probably bypass the re-installing step by just changing it the file referenced in your traceback -- It even gives you the line number):

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Gnuplot/utils.py", line 33, in float_array
    return numpy.asarray(m, numpy.float32)
```

Now that line 33 reads `numpy.asarray(m,numpy.float64)`,

---

we can use floating point numbers to store the epoch information (`float32` just doesn't give enough precision I don't think ...)

```
def secs_since_epoch(date_time,epoch=datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)):
    """
    compute seconds since a particular epoch.  The default epoch is the unix
    epoch -- e.g. Jan. 1 1970.
    """
    dt = date_time - epoch  #time elapsed since unix epoch
    return dt.days*24*3600 + dt.seconds + dt.microseconds*1e-6 #converted to seconds
```

You can use this function on your datetime objects to transform them from a datetime object to a simple (double precision) float.  Gnuplot can thankfully read this format for time objects as well:

```
gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
gp('set data style linespoints')
gp('set xdata time')
gp('set timefmt "%s"')
xmin = secs_since_epoch(datetime.datetime(2012,12,20,0,0))
xmax = secs_since_epoch(datetime.datetime(2012,2,12,0,0))
gp('set xrange [%s:%s]' % (xmin,xmax) )
gp.plot(data)
```

---

The following script works alright for me:

```
import datetime
import Gnuplot

data = [[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 15, 17, 45), 16.00],
        [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 16, 17, 45), 15.98],
        [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 17, 17, 45), 15.94]]

def secs_since_epoch(date_time,epoch=datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)):
    """
    compute seconds since a particular epoch.  The default epoch is the unix
    epoch -- e.g. Jan. 1 1970.
    """
    dt = date_time - epoch  #time elapsed since unix epoch
    return dt.days*24*3600 + dt.seconds + dt.microseconds*1e-6 #converted to seconds

dt,vals = zip(*data)
data = zip(map(secs_since_epoch,dt),vals)

gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(debug=True)
gp('set style data linespoints')
gp('set xdata time')
gp('set timefmt "%s"')
xmin = secs_since_epoch(datetime.datetime(2012,12,20,0,0))
xmax = secs_since_epoch(datetime.datetime(2012,2,12,0,0))
#gp('set xrange [%s:%s]' % (xmin,xmax) )
d = Gnuplot.Data(data)
d.set_option(using="1:2")
gp.plot(d)
raw_input()
```

Comment: I have changed line 33 in utils.py to float64, as you recommended. Same output, but with float64 in line 33. Then, I have reinstalled python-gnuplot. It is as it was float32 in line 33.

Comment: @DaniloMitrovic -- There are more subleties here than I initially anticipated, Most of them involving gnuplot's timeformat requiring a using spec. -- However, It looks like I got a working version.  Also, reading the comments in the source makes it appear that we don't actually need to change `numpy.float32` to `numpy.float64` as it appears that `float32` will throw an exception if it can't fit a value and then gnuplotpy tries again with a larger datatype.